# PHP MySQL PDO takes 1 second to connect on GAE to Google SQL

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, pdo

I've seen many questions where people ask why their PDO connections take one second and the answer is always: change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

But in my situation, I have a Google App Engine App connecting to Google SQL and I'm am feeling that 1 second badly.

My connection line is:

```
$this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->settings["user"], $this->settings["password"], array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
            ));
```

Where `$dsn` is: `"mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/projectid:asia-east1:db;dbname=mydb"`

Can I speed this connection up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this issue by creating a new database instance in the same region as the App Engine project then export/importing my data.

Testing results have gone from just over 1000 milliseconds to less than 50 during the connection!